# Unable to properly return python data in function

Tags: python, function, while-loop, binary

I've been at this for hours and hours. I think my problem is I need to use a return in my first function so that I can use this function as an argument in my second function. However, it seems that if I use a return, the data is somehow not being passed properly to the second function. I say that because I can't seem to format it properly if i comment out my print statement and only use a return (the return statement won't let me include the end = '' so it comes out vertically instead). Then the second function just spits out the first digit of my first function's return. I'm so lost and i need to get some sleep now I guess. Been up all night with this. Is there some way I can return the data int he first function and make it be a nice horizontal string like it would be if I used my print statement instead? (Or does that not matter and I'm way off track?) Please let me know if I can clarify something. Just a nudge in the right direction would help.

> Instructions: Write a program that takes in a positive integer as
> input, and outputs a string of 1's and 0's representing the integer in
> binary. For an integer x, the algorithm is:
>
> As long as x is greater than 0
> Output x % 2 (remainder is either 0 or 1)
> x = x // 2

> Note: The above algorithm outputs the 0's and 1's
> in reverse order. You will need to write a second function to reverse
> the string.
>
> Ex: If the input is:6
>
> the output is:
> 110

> The program must define and call the following two functions.
> Define a function named int_to_reverse_binary() that takes an integer
> as a parameter and returns a string of 1's and 0's representing the
> integer in binary (in reverse).

> Define a function named
> string_reverse() that takes an input string as a parameter and returns
> a string representing the input string in reverse. def
> int_to_reverse_binary(integer_value) def string_reverse(input_string)

My code:

## Define your functions here.

```
def int_to_reverse_binary(int_number):
    while int_number > 0:
       #print (int_number % 2, end='')
       return int_number % 2
       int_number = int_number // 2
       

def string_reverse(input_string):
    for i in reversed(str(input_string)):
        print(i,end='')
        
    
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Type your code here. 
    # Your code must call int_to_reverse_binary() to get 
    # the binary string of an integer in a reverse order.
    # Then call string_reverse() to reverse the string
    # returned from int_to_reverse_binary().
    x = int(input())
    int_to_reverse_binary(x)
    string_reverse(int_to_reverse_binary(x))
```

1: Compare output
0 / 2
Output differs. See highlights below.
Input
6
Your output
0
Expected output
110

2: Unit test
0 / 2
Convert 19 to binary using int_to_reverse_binary() and string_reverse()
Your output
1
Test feedback
string_reverse(user_input) did not return a value.
Your function may be missing a return statement.

3: Unit test
0 / 3
Convert 255 to binary using int_to_reverse_binary() and string_reverse()
Your output
1
Test feedback
string_reverse(user_input) did not return a value.
Your function may be missing a return statement.

Comment: `return` will end your function and return the value after `return` keyword. So you will need a variable to store your reversed string and return only after you are done with the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement in Python also acts as the ending point of the function. i.e. no statement will be executed once a return statement is encountered in a function. So, when the `while` loop is being executed, the interpreter sees a return statement and stops executing any further. If you wish to return multiple values from the function you can do 2 things,

1. Instead of using a while loop in s function, use the function in the while loop:
   Sample Code:

```
def foo(num):
    return num % 2

i = 0
while i< 10:
    print(foo(i))
    i += 1
```

2. Use a `list` to return all values at once. Sample Code:

```
def foo(num):
    a = []
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        a.append(i)
        i+=1
print(foo(10))
```

Code With corrections:

```
def int_to_reverse_binary(int_number):
    # print('i', int_number)
    a = []
    while int_number > 0:
        a.append(int_number % 2)
        int_number = int_number // 2
    # print('a', a)
    return a
       
def string_reverse(input_string):
    print(''.join([str(i) for i in input_string])[::-1])
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    # a = int_to_reverse_binary(x)
    string_reverse(int_to_reverse_binary(x))
```

Comment: than you...hopefully I get better at this eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made this unnecessarily complex. f-string formatting will give you the binary representation of your integer then reverse the string with a slice as follows:

```
def int_to_reverse_binary(int_number):
    return f'{int_number:b}'[::-1]

print(int_to_reverse_binary(100))
```

**Output:**

```
0010011
```